# Android SimpleCursorAdapter - Adding conditional images

Tags: android, simplecursoradapter

So I'm using SimpleCursorAdapter to adapt data from SQLite into ListView. Lets call this database testData. One of my columns in testData records true or false with either 0 or 1. Can I make the listview display a different image for each item according to whether that row has 0 or 1?

This is the adapter that I'm using.

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
this, 
android.R.layout.two_line_list_item,  
mCursor,                                              
new String[] {testData.DATE1, testData.NAME1},           
new int[] {android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2});
```

Answer (score 4):

I created a customized SimpleCursorAdapter:

```
public class MySimpleCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

    public MySimpleCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor cur,
             String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, layout, cur, from, to);
    }

    @Override public void setViewImage(ImageView iv, String text)
    {
        if (text.equals("0")) {
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.new1);
        }
        else {
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.check1);
        }
    }

}
```

In my ListActivity I bind the text field in the database to the image resource id. In your example it would look like this:

```
ListAdapter adapter = new MySimpleCursorAdapter(
    this, 
    android.R.layout.two_line_list_item,  
    mCursor,                                              
    new String[] {testData.DATE1, testData.NAME1},           
    new int[] {android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.image1}); // Note: replace text2 with image1
```

I.e. if the text field "Name1" in your database contains "0", the image "new1" will be displayed in the ListView, and if it has another value, "check1" will be displayed.